# XSLT Generating multiple output

Tags: xslt

I have an xml document. from that xml I need to generate multiple xml using xslt.
for example.

```
<Class>
<Student>
<name>First</name>
<age></age>
</Student>
<Student>
<name>Second</name>
<age></age>
</Student>
</Class>.
```

From this xml I need to generate one xml with First student and another with Second student.

Comment: Not sure, what You want do do. Can't you just run multiple transformations? From the command line, from a java program, from ... Please elaborate.

Comment: Is it possible to do with single xslt? My requirement is to generate multile output xml from a single one.in the example i have provided two student elements.thats why two output xmls each contain one student element.if my input has 3 student element i need 3 output xmls

Comment: @Jithin "*Is it possible to do with single xslt?*" It's possible if you you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor - or an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports the EXSLT `xsl:document` extension instruction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this spiltter

```
<xsl:template match="Class">
        <xsl:for-each select="Student">
                <xsl:result-document href="{position()}.xml" method="xml">
                        <Class>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
                        </Class>
                </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note that this requires XSLT 2.0.